# Select foreign key for sub query when there are more than one candidates

Tags: soql, subquery

In our Asset object, we have the standard Contact field (who, in our case, is the person who purchased the Asset).
We also have a second Lookup(Contact) called Member__c who is the beneficary of the Asset, as people can purchase Assets on behalf of other people.
(for context, the Asset can represent a Membership - a parent may purchase for their child. In this case, the parent is referenced in the Contact field and the child in the Member__c field).
In short, on the Asset object, we have these two fields:

| Name | API Name | Data Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Contact | Contact | Lookup(Contact) |
| Member Beneficiary | Member__c | Lookup(Contact) |

Now, if I want to get all the Assets that applies to a Member (not whether they purchased it or not), and I use this SSOQL:

```
[SELECT Id, Name__c, Date_First_Joined_BE__c, CreatedDate,
    (SELECT Name, Expiry_Date__c, Effective_From__c
    FROM Assets
    WHERE Expiry_Date__c >= TODAY
    AND Effective_From__c <= TODAY
    ORDER BY Expiry_Date__c DESC)
FROM Contact WHERE ID IN: memberIds]
```

It joins on the Asset.Contact field, not the Asset.Member__c field - I get, for each person, a list of the Assets (memberships) they purchased, not the memberships that apply to them.

If I try something like:

```
[SELECT Id, Name__c, Date_First_Joined_BE__c, CreatedDate,
    (SELECT Name, Expiry_Date__c, Effective_From__c
    FROM Assets
    WHERE Expiry_Date__c >= TODAY
    AND Effective_From__c <= TODAY
    AND Member__c = c.Id
    ORDER BY Expiry_Date__c DESC)
FROM Contact c WHERE ID IN: memberIds]
```

As you would do in SQL, I just get 'unknown error parsing query' (In Dev Console)

So, How do I select the foreign key to join on when there are multiple candidates?

Answer (score 1):

Each foreign key has its own "relationship name". You'll need to check your setup to see what the custom name looks like, but it'll look something like:

```
[SELECT Id, Name__c, Date_First_Joined_BE__c, CreatedDate,
    (SELECT Name, Expiry_Date__c, Effective_From__c
    FROM Assets__r
    WHERE Expiry_Date__c >= TODAY
    AND Effective_From__c <= TODAY
    ORDER BY Expiry_Date__c DESC)
FROM Contact WHERE ID IN: memberIds]
```

You can find the custom relationship name in Setup > Object Manager > Contacts > Fields & Relationships > (select the Member__c field).

It's not possible for one object to have the same relationship name more than once, so you'll always have a unique way to address your subquery.